# SSRS formatting question - Need item highlighted

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a report that is using a Join(Lookupset) function to return a list of items.  I have it formatted using HTML tags and it is working great.  Here is the code:

`=Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.JOIN(LookupSet(Fields!Tract_ID.Value,Fields!PROPERTYID.Value,"<b>" & Fields!STIPULATIONTITLE.Value & " -- " & "</b>" & Fields!STIPULATIONTEXT.Value, "MyDataset"), "<br>")`

Now, what I need to have happen is if the STIPULATIONTITLE that returns contains the word "EXCLUSIVE" only that row is Highlighted.

I can't seem to get that working.  I can get the entire textbox to highlight, but not only that specific row.

Can anyone help me with the HTML that would do that?

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this at th emoment but I would have thought the following would work..

Try wrapping the `"<b>" & Fields!STIPULATIONTITLE.Value & " -- " & "</b>"` in an `IIF`.

Something like

```
IIF (Fields!STIPULATIONTITLE.Value.ToString().Contains("EXCLUSIVE")
    , "<b>" & Fields!STIPULATIONTITLE.Value & " -- " & "</b>"
    , Fields!STIPULATIONTITLE.Value)
```

If you replace the `"<b>" & Fields!STIPULATIONTITLE.Value & " -- " & "</b>"` part with the entire expression above it might do what you want.

As I said, untested...

Comment: Thanks for this.  It pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Lag it's sorted, if you feel this answered the question ,please mark it answered. If you only found it useful, please vote the answer up.  You should also mark one of the answers (yours or mine) as accepted so that others searching for similar answers can find it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after many attempts, I think I got it sort of working using this code:

`=Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.JOIN(LookupSet(Fields!Tract_ID.Value,Fields!PROPERTYID.Value, iif((Fields!STIPULATIONTITLE.Value.Contains("rossing") AND Fields!PRIORITYDD.Value = "Critical"), "<b><font color = 'red'><font size = 3>" & Fields!STIPULATIONTITLE.Value & " -- " & Fields!STIPULATIONTEXT.Value & "</b></font></font>", "<b>" & Fields!STIPULATIONTITLE.Value & " -- " & "</b>" & Fields!STIPULATIONTEXT.Value), "MyDataset"), "<br>")`

It doesn't do the Highlighting (couldn't get that working), but it does turn the font RED for that line only.

Comment: unless I'm misreading it, you are wrapping the whole things in bold tags not matter what the content it. Try setting the textbox to not render as html so you can see what html you are generating. I think my answer probably works but you need to drop the other bold tags. Anyway, glad it's sorted.